# Pop up at a particular time

Tags: visualforce

I want to display a pop up message with 2 buttons proceed and cancel from vf page on clicking edit button between 10 to 11 pm PST.I don't know how to add this time parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The [System.Now()](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_now) method returns the current date and time in the GMT time zone. Using the [Datetime.Format()](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_format) method, you can convert it to PST

For Example:

```
Integer currentPSTHourValue = Integer.valueOf(System.Now().format('HH', 'PST'));
```

Now that you have the hour value, simply check if it is in a given range and execute your business logic accordingly.

Comment: i have used -                                                                                              rendered="{!IF(Integer.valueOf(System.Now().format('HH','PST'))>3,true,false)}"              but its saying missing')' Please guide

Comment: do this calculation in controller of the vf page and then use the variable in the  rendered condition rendered="{!IF(currentPSTHourValue>3,true,false)}", in your controller you would have a variable public currentPSTHourValue {get;set;} and the currentPSTHourValue = Integer.valueOf(System.Now().format('HH', 'PST')); could be in the constructor

Comment: thanks Rajiv. It should work. Can you help in one more thing. On clicking edit button i want a pop up. Currently there is a edit page which is overriding my edit button. But now on clicking edit button i want a pop-up. On that popup if user clicks on Proceed then it should go to my edit page. Please guide.